# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$db'

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$result = mysqli_query ("INSERT INTO users (tower,adress,floor,area,price,status) VALUES('$tower','$adress','$floor','$area','$price','$status'" $db, db1 )") or die("Unable to connect to base");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставьте запятую перед $db и замените после него db1 на $db1. И возможно $$area надо заменить на $area